# WeBlog Module (Release 3.1) - Word Press Blog Site Migration to Sitecore 8.2

Tags: weblog

We have a requirement, where we need to migrate Blog Sites in Wordpress to Sitecore. We are using WeBlog Module(Release 3.1) to migrate in Sitecore 8.2

I downloaded the module from GitHub, and followed the instructions to set it up. After setup, when I try to import the XML Export File from Wordpress, using the module from Sitecore, it gets failed. I am not able to see any error on the page.

Can you please let me know, what more I need to do in order to make it work? Also, any leads where I can find the logs will also be very helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Sharad Kumar Sangal

Comment: It's a known issue:
https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/263

Are you sure that there is nothing in the logs? I can suggest this small exe to validate XML: https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/253#issuecomment-343414007
With help of it you might find what value is a problem for the importer. Are you using SPEAK or old importer?

Comment: Thanks Alan. It helped to find out errors with XML. The Import ran successfully.

Comment: moved my comment to answer. You can accept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue: 
[github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/263](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/263)

I can suggest this small exe to validate XML:

https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/253#issuecomment-343414007

With help of it you might find what value is a problem for the importer.